# Applying 'Where' to LINQ causes type conversion error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, type-conversion

Probably a straight forward question, and probably a duplicate which I cannot find.

I'm applying a filter to a Linq query, but I'm doing it wrong.  What's the correct way?

```
var cities = db.Cities; 
cities = cities.Where(p => p.CityName == "New York");
```

This gives a compile error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<
>   Database.Cities >' to 'System.Data.Linq.Table< Database.Cities >'. An
>   explicit conversion exists.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752135/basic-linqtosql-question-why-wont-this-compile

Comment: And there is the duplicate with the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
IQueryable<Cities> lstCities = db.Cities.Where(p=>p.CityName.Equals("New York"));
```